# How do I run the loop 3 times?

Tags: go

**Task:**
`You are making a robot that can speak numbers. Your robot should take 3 numbers in the range of 0-10 as input and output the corresponding texts in English.`

**pre-solution:**
[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/vcba-MyRpzF)

```
func main() {
num := 0
var input int
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    num += 1
    switch num {
    case 1:
        fmt.Println("One")
    case 2:
        fmt.Println("Two")
    case 3:
        fmt.Println("Three")
    case 4:
        fmt.Println("Four")
    case 5:
        fmt.Println("Five")
    case 6:
        fmt.Println("Six")
    case 7:
        fmt.Println("Seven")
    case 8:
        fmt.Println("Eight")
    case 9:
        fmt.Println("Nine")
    case 10:
        fmt.Println("Ten")

    }
}
```

}

**Question:**
How do I run the loop 3 times?
more details: https://www.sololearn.com/learning/eom-project/1164/1188

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func robot(d, e, f int) (string, string, string) {
   m := map[int]string{
      0: "zero", 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four",
      5: "five", 6: "six", 7: "seven", 8: "eight", 9: "nine", 10: "ten",
   }
   return m[d], m[e], m[f]
}

func main() {
   s, t, u := robot(1, 2, 3)
   fmt.Printf("%q %q %q\n", s, t, u)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The task states that you need to make Input 3 digits and the output should be there should be texts I did it and passed all

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var input int
    var i = 1
    for {
        fmt.Scanln(&input)
        if input >= 0 && input <= 10 {
            switch input {
            case 0:
                fmt.Println("Zero")
            case 1:
                fmt.Println("One")
            case 2:
                fmt.Println("Two")
            case 3:
                fmt.Println("Three")
            case 4:
                fmt.Println("Four")
            case 5:
                fmt.Println("Five")
            case 6:
                fmt.Println("Six")
            case 7:
                fmt.Println("Seven")
            case 8:
                fmt.Println("Eight")
            case 9:
                fmt.Println("Nine")
            case 10:
                fmt.Println("Ten")
            }
            if i == 3 {
                break
            }
            i++
        }
    }
}
```